# Apache Daemon trying to Ping on CentOS but not working (SELinux issue)

Tags: apache, centos, ping, selinux

I have developped an application in php. One of its functions is to ping an external server.
However, when this action was fired nothing happened. I checked the SELinux log and generated a policy to allow apache daemon to ping (ping works fine if log in as  apache user). After installing that policy, no error is shown on SELinux log, but on the httpd log appears a lot of times:

```
ping: recvmsg: Permission denied
```

I know it is a SELinux configuration problem (Socket connection maybe?) because if I disable it, it works nice, but this is not an option for me.

I have redirected the output of the ping command to a text file and, after firing the action, this is the result:

```
PING myhost (myip) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- myhost ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13002ms
```

So I am kind of stuck at this point. Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhpas the apache daemon is not allowed to execute ping?

Comment: I think it is, because the ping is executed but with error.

I have updated the question with more info about it.

Comment: Seems like it is blocking `ping` replies from coming back - can anyone ping your machine from outside? If you enable that, maybe this will work.

Comment: Yes, I can ping it without problems.

Comment: Try this: make yourself the apache process `sudo su apache` and then see if you can ping outside. That is the webserver process, but root can _become_ that user and try things.

Comment: I have tried it and I can ping outside. This is weird... Thanks a lot for your effort, by the way.

Comment: Errmm... did you try rebooting? :D Also, how about using the `exec` command from PHP to execute ping on the shell rather than calling ping directly?

Comment: It seems that I finally solved it. I had to reinstall CentoOS. The problem, I guess, was that I messed a lot with policies, installing new ones in order to solve my problem. After a fresh installed, it worked flawlessly.
Thanks a lot, @Sudipta.

Comment: Glad to hear that - vote the last "rebooting" answer up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fresh install it all worked. Don't mess with policies, kids.